# How to display content to cell using textLabel.text to a TableView object in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I want to add a simple string to the textLabel.text property then display it in the cells in this example.

I added the number of sections, the number of rows in that section, and now trying to display data to the cells.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

// number of sections in table view
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// number of rows in section
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

// returns the content of each row
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // an object to represent each cell
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    // configure
    cell.textLabel?.text? = "Hello"       - this is where i run into a problem
    //cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"      - this is where i run into a problem
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What result does your current code produce? Your commented out line (no "?" on text) works fine for me.

Comment: Problem: the cells return no data.  Result:  Just endless lines of the table view.  I commented out the line in order to test the one above it but neither one works.

Comment: Your commented line should work. Is numberOfRowsInSection being called?

Answer (score 0):

The ViewController was not configured as the delegate.